# ReduceByKey in python

Tags: python, pyspark

Is there a function in Python that do exactly as `reduceByKey` in Spark (PySpark):

```
a.reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
```

For example:

```
a = [(1, ['a']),
     (1, ['b']),   
     (2, ['c']),   
     (2, ['d']),   
     (3, ['e'])]
```

to

```
b = [(1,['a','b']),
     (2,['c','d']),
     (3,['e']),
```

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of. But it's easy to write one yourself.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def reduce_by_key(ls):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for key, sublist in ls:
        d.setdefault(key, []).extend(sublist)
    return list(d.items())
```

If order doesn't need to preserved, a regular `dict` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. Probably the closest thing you can get is [`toolz.itertoolz.reduceby`](https://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.reduceby) although it has different semantics (is applied in a streaming manner so it doesn't assume associativity or commutativity). It also reduces over complete objects and returns a dictionary:

```
list(reduceby(first, lambda x, y: (first(x), second(x) + second(y)), a).values())
## [(1, ['a', 'b']), (2, ['c', 'd']), (3, ['e'])]
```